# travelling tournament assignment

Tags: tournament

I'm working on a schedule of a football tournament with integer programming. Using LINGO software as a tool to work on it. Minimize traveling distance is my objective. There are 12 teams and i already have the distance matrix between each team.
In my mind, there will be quadratic assignment.

This is the objective function:

![objective function] >>> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx3we.png)

Dij is the physical distance between home base team i and j. index k (away team home base) as the representative to a location where team i do the away game in team j home base. last, t as the representative to matchday (1..(n-1)), n = teams involved.

this is the sets and data (LINGO) :

![sets and data] >>> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Ua8.png)

is there anything wrong in the sets of the data? because i feel that the quadratic should be assign to (maybe) team,team,matchday and team,team,index k? can you help me with the script?

i am a beginner in LINGO software and any help really appreciated.
thanks.